# Must I declare variables inherited from the parent class? (PHP 5.3.2)

Tags: php, oop

I am new at writing OOP.

I thought that properties of the parent were automatically inherited by the child unless defined in the child class.

I have a parent class like:

```
class parentClass {
  public $name;
}
.
.
.

class childClass extends parentClass {
  protected $id;
  protected $frontend_name;
}
```

When I try to load them, I get this error:

PHP Fatal error: Access level to childClass::$name must be public (as in class parentClass) in /var/wwww/model.php on line 2571

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code:

```
class parentClass {
    public $name = 'foo';
}

class childClass extends parentClass {
    protected $id;
    protected $frontend_name;
}
```

Calling from child class

```
$child = new childClass;
echo $child->name;
```

Or calling from parent class

```
$parent = new parentClass;
echo $parent->name;
```

Result:

```
foo
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. That's what I thought. I'm not sure why I had the error. I changed nothing but resaved the file and the error disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

Declaring the variable again is going to throw an error because you've already inherited them from the parent class. So, no, you must not declare variables inherited from the parent class.

Comment: I can define to overwrite the var.

Comment: "Declaring the variable again is going to throw an error because you've already inherited them from the parent class. So, no, you must not declare variables inherited from the parent class."
That is totally and utterly wrong. Thanks for wasting my time, Harry.

Comment: BZZT! Oh, I'm sorry, but thank you for playing!  You can override anything you like in a subclass, unless it was declared "final" in the superclass.  The only restrictions are on member visibility, you can't reduce the visibility of a member when you redeclare it.  Something that was public in the superclass can't be redeclared private or protected in the subclass.